# Kalman filter, multiple lines tracking

Tags: filter, tracking, lines, kalman-filter

I have a problem with multiple lines tracking by using Kalman filter.
Input data - number of items and set of structures with x1,y1, x2,y2 (coordinates). For each iteration the number of items can be different so some lines can appear or disappear.

For single line it looks simple - we have input data, equasions etc. and we can create output. We always know the line can exist. If not, and it will appear later - it will be still the same line.

But for multiple lines I don't know how to start - in one iteration I can get few objects - ok, I will use this set of equasions for each of them. But in next iteration I can get less of more lines. I'm not sure what's the correct approach - I have data from previous iteration but I will need to use it for the same object. So:
1. I need to find it - checking distance between middlepoints for pair estimated previously <-> line N and choosing the smallest value? Is it correct approach or we have different method?
2. Storing old data - the line was visible long time but after next iteration will never appear. I got new line and again - the same situation. It will be good to store old results but in this case, after looong time, I will have a lot of zombie-data. Do we have some special criteria to clean it or I need to use some own ideas like max iterations if no detection etc.?